# Virtualhost in Apache (wildcard and static domain)

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, subdomain, virtualhost

I have some odd situation. I wan to make different DirectoryRoot for one domain.

example.com -> /dir1 www.example.com -> /dir1

*.example.com -> /dir2

I'm trying settings with NameVirtualHost and ServerAlias. Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/dir1
<VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName other.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/dir2
<VirtualHost>
```

The order is important - the 'www' vHost must precede the wildcard.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758351/virtualhost-for-wildcard-subdomain-and-static-subdomain

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot = /var/www/wildcard
      ServerName other.example.com
      ServerAlias *.example.com
    <VirtualHost>

This is not working. It is only forking for other.example.com. When I'm browsking to aaaa.example.com is is loading content form /var/www/example not from /var/www/wildcard

Comment: The equal signs should not have been present - I have edited the example above, hopefully it work for you.